# How to use mgarchbekk package in R?

Tags: r, time-series, quantitative-finance

I am trying to estimate BEKK Garch model by using mgarchBEKK pachage, which is available [**here**](https://rdrr.io/cran/mgarchBEKK/man/BEKK.html#heading-6).

```
library(quantmod)
library(rugarch)
library(mgarchBEKK)

eps<- read.csv("C.csv", header=TRUE)

  > head(eps)

       v1        v2
1 -0.001936598  0.001968415
2 -0.000441797 -0.002724438
3  0.003752762 -0.010221719
4 -0.004511632 -0.014637860
5 -0.001426905  0.010597786
6  0.007435739 -0.005880712
> tail(eps)
           v1           v2
1954 -0.043228944  0.0000530712
1955  0.082546871 -0.0028188110
1956  0.025058992  0.0058264010
1957  0.001751445 -0.0298050150
1958 -0.007973320 -0.0037243560
1959 -0.005207348  0.0012664230

## Simulate a BEKK process:
simulated <- simulateBEKK(2,1959, c(1,1), params = NULL)


## Prepare the input for the estimation process:
simulated1 <- do.call(cbind, simulated$eps)

## Estimate with default arguments:
estimated <- BEKK(simulated1)

  H IS SINGULAR!...
H IS SINGULAR!...
Warning message:
In BEKK(simulated1) : negative inverted hessian matrix element


## Show diagnostics:
diagnoseBEKK(estimated)

## Likewise, you can estimate an mGJR process:
estimated2 <- mGJR(simulated[,1], simulated[,2])
```

I don't know, what is the problem in my code, because in results it is showing 3968 number of series, instead of 2 series.

Answer (score 1):

You are **estimating** a model.

***What does that mean?***

To quote my statistics professors, the philosophy is to "find a stochastic model which may have created the observed series."

That is exactly what the mgarchBEKK is doing. The model is being fitted to the data you supplied (your V1 and V2 series). In simple words this means, that a lot of different parameter combinations are tried out and of those (in your case 3968 tries) the combination that "fits best" is what you see in your results.

I did the same with 3 time series of the length 8596. My results look something like this:

```
Number of estimated series :  25788 
Length of estimated series :  8596 
Estimation Time            :  3.258482
```

So the number of estimated series is way above the 3 vectors I used.

The estimates look something like this (since this is a bi- or multivariate model-estimation you have parameter matrices, not single values as you would have with a one dimensional GARCH model):

```
C estimates:
      [,1]      [,2]        [,3]
      [1,] 0.9797469 0.2189191 0.202451941
      [2,] 0.0000000 1.0649323 0.003050169
      [3,] 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.896492130

ARCH estimates:
        [,1]         [,2]        [,3]
        [1,]  0.29110077 -0.008445699 0.008570904
        [2,] -0.02109381  0.419092657 0.325321939
        [3,] -0.01280835 -0.057648910 0.482502301

GARCH estimates:
        [,1]        [,2]        [,3]
        [1,] -0.27770297  0.03587415 -0.73029389
        [2,] -0.05172256 -0.25601327  0.01918367
        [3,]  0.07945086  0.03364686 -0.50664759
```

I can't describe the math behind this fitting, as far as I know some form of [maximum likelihood estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation) is used.

I'm a rookie in statistics, so if anything I said is wrong please feel free to correct me.